# Hibernate, isAssociationType? How do I find out if an entity field is an association?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am looking to create a criteria query, on association only if it is an assoication.

There are so many types such as Date, Map, Set, int, Integer, Long and so on that make it hard to properly check if **a declared field is an association.**

Is there a simple way to find this out using Hibernate already?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is in `org.hibernate.type.Type#isAssociationType()`

For example

```
ClassMetadata cmd  = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Hibernate.getClass(entity));
String[] propertyNames = cmd.getPropertyNames();
for (String name : propertyNames) {
    if (cmd.getPropertyType(name).isAssociationType()) {
        // association type
    }
}
```